# AWS, running multiple server on the same instance for same type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

AWS said when we deploy the same type of application, it is better to deploy on the same server instances.

I am not sure if it is a best/better practise for deployment.
Is there any further references for that?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingapps-multiple.html

Running Multiple Applications on the Same Application Server

If you have multiple applications of the same type, it is sometimes more cost-effective to run them on the same application server instances.

To run multiple applications on the same server

Add an app to the stack for each application.

Obtain a separate subdomain for each app and map the subdomains to the application server's or load balancer's IP address.

Edit each app's configuration to specify the appropriate subdomain.

For more information on how to perform these tasks, see Using Custom Domains.

Answer (score 0):

They don't actually say 'its better', they say it is more cost effecient. If the instance you are running on has excess capacity, and money is a concern, why not use it?

If money is no object, by all means run just a single app on each instance. It does give you a bit more flexibility and a cleaner seperation between the duties of each server. i.e. if you had just a single app on a single instance, if you didn't need the app anymore you could terminate the instance.